# Android enableUI(bool) documentation?

Tags: java, android, javadoc, ioio

There are two parts to this question.

Generally, when you see a method call in a Java code example, how can you tell what library it is being called from so that you can look up the Javadoc?

Specifically, in many of the IOIO examples the method `enableUI(true);` is called and I'd like to know more about that method so I can use it properly in my own code. Where is **this** `enableUI()` documented? When I use the search engines, I find lots of methods named `enableUI()` that are different and not related to this one.

Kevin

Comment: When you try `ctrl+clicking` on the method, where does it take you?

Comment: That was it. The method is defined elsewhere in the same example. The ctrl-click is the tip I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shark got it - `ctrl-click` on method call.